# CSS table based layout row is not extending 100% width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to extend the width of a css table based row to 100% browser width without breaking the layout of the rest of the content. Notice the green header bar is not extending full width even though it has been set to 100% width.

My code can be found here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HfnFv

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    overflow:visible;
    height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;
}
.header{background:green;position:absolute;}
.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
  position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}
.trow{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}
.left{
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    color:#efefef;
    display:table-cell;
}
.left p{
    margin:100px 0;
}
.right{
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    color:#efefef;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
<div class="trow header">
<p>
test
</p>
</div>
<div class="trow">
<div class="left">
<p>
test
</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
test
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Added

```
position:absolute;
```

to the header row.

But I would love to see an alternate solution that does not absolutely position the child element.

Comment: it seems to be working to me

Comment: added position:absolute to the row, but would like to see some alternate method if possible.

Comment: Place the relevant code in the question itself. Please try to better explain your issue

Comment: I clearly said extend the width of a table based row. A table based row is: display:table-row, what is confusing about the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because we cant simulate `colspan` with css. As you have one row above another row that contains two cells, this header row supposedly should be `colspan="2"`. But as it is not possible, your options are:

1. Change your structure.
2. If you want keep you structure as it is now your only option is set
   your `.header`, using `display:table-caption;` and `caption-side:top;` as the example below:

CSS:

```
.trow.header{
    width:100%;
    display:table-caption;
    caption-side:top;
    background:green;
}
```

I made a demo with your own example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3JQcb/

Comment: what structure would you recommend @LGVentura ?

Comment: @AntonB i recommend you this http://jsfiddle.net/fFeKs/ it fits perfect width 100% and height 100%

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
.trow{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}
```

To:

```
.trow{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
```

EDIT change .trow back and add:

```
.header{
    display:table;
}
```

directly after it

Comment: then that destroys the full-height of the rows?

Comment: notice red and blue colums are not 100% height anymore. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HfnFv

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="table">
    <div class="trow header">
    <p>
    test
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="trow">
    <div class="left">
    <p>
    test
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    test
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
overflow:visible;
height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;
}
.header{background:green;position:absolute;}
.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}
.trow{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}
.left{
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    color:#efefef;
    display:table-cell;
}
.left p{
    margin:100px 0;
}
.right{
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    color:#efefef;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: OP said they wanted alternatives to having .header absolute

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be the following.

There is really no need for absolute positioning of any element in this situation.

In this example, we have a two horizontal blocks (.row). The first with a width of 100% and the second with a max width (62.5rem/1000px).

I use Foundation quite a bit, so I kept the naming conventions; although these are the bare bones and the framework isn't necessary in this example.

**css**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%; }

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 62.5rem;
}
  .row p {
    padding: 1rem;
  }

.column,
.columns {
  padding-left: 0.9375rem;
  padding-right: 0.9375rem;
  width: 100%;
  float: left; 
}

.row.max-width {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
  .row.max-width .columns {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right:0;
  }

.header{background:green;}

.table{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
  .table p {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
.trow{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.left{
  width:30%;
  background-color:#990000;
  color:#efefef;
  display:table-cell;
}

.right{
  width:70%;
  background-color:blue;
  color:#efefef;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

**markup**

```
<div class="row max-width">
  <div class="trow header">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <h1>Row above 100%</h1>
    <h2>Row below -- max-width 62.5em</h2>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="trow">
      <div class="left">
        <p>test</p>
      </div>

      <div class="right">
        <p>test</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle created here:
http://jsfiddle.net/squashriddle/y9kT9/