# css bottom poperty works strange

Tags: html, css

I know that im missing something simple, but i can't get what exactly

HTML:

```
<div class="form-captions">
  <div class="form-text">
    Caption
  </div>
  <div class="form_error" style="display: block;">
    sfgsdfg
    asdf safgsafdgsdfgsdfgsdfghsdfhsdghs
    asfdasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsdf
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix{
  clear: both;
}
.form-captions {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.form-text {
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 20px;
    color: rgb( 29, 29, 29 );
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    bottom: 0;
}

.form_error {
    color: darkred;
    float: right;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 65%;
}
```

For the form-text block bottom works not from the bottom of the form-captions block (same position "with top: 0;"). But it works and reacts on value changes.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/181Lky0n/1/)

How can i make it works from the bottom or how can i move the text to of this block to the bottom of the "form-captions"?

Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe show a screenshot of the desired result?

Comment: [here](http://i.imgur.com/5Am1fM2.png)

Comment: do you mean something like that https://jsfiddle.net/181Lky0n/6/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right your question, the solution I found is based on display:table solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20669539)

In form-caption I added display:table-row, while in form-text I removed all fide sizes and make it display as table-cell.

```css
.clearfix{
  clear: both;
}
.form-captions {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: table-row;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.form-text {
    
    font-size: 16px;
   
    color: rgb( 29, 29, 29 );
    text-align: left;
    
    display: table-cell;
    bottom: 0;
}

.form_error {
    color: darkred;
    float: right;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-captions">
<div class="form-text">
                        Caption
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_error" style="display: block;">sfgsdfg
                    asdf safgsafdgsdfgsdfgsdfghsdfhsdghs
asfdasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsdf</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one helped me, thank you.
Strange  that there was no solution on relative display type.

Comment: I am glad to be helpful!

Comment: the only thing, i've got a problem with width 100% this way, but i've found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153473/css-table-based-layout-row-is-not-extending-100-width)

Comment: ofc i was going to write block instead of relative in 1st comment

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try this -

```css
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.form-captions {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.form-text {
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  color: rgb( 29, 29, 29);
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  bottom:0
  
}

.form_error {
  color: darkred;
  float: right;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-captions">
  <div class="form-text">
    Caption
  </div>
  <div class="form_error" style="display: block;">sfgsdfg asdf safgsafdgsdfgsdfgsdfghsdfhsdghs asfdasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfgsdf
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "position: absolute;" moving this block out from containing element, i've already tried this

Comment: @CrazyWu what's wrong with this solution? it seems to do what you are asking for.

Comment: @Aziz only if you have no more html on the page after this block.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/181Lky0n/2/ .Let me know if this is what you were looking for. Also the changes was just increasing the div width.

```
.form_error {
    color: darkred;
    float: right;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 100%; // this is the change
}
```

**EDIT:**  here is the updated [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/181Lky0n/13/) and the result is

[image]

Comment: No, this block doesn't needs to be changed at all, i'm talking about moving .form-text to the bottom, please look [here](http://i.imgur.com/5Am1fM2.png)

Comment: "position: absolute;" moving this block out from containing element, if you have more html after this block it wouldn't work

Comment: "position: absolute;" will make the element to be absolute to the parent and only then you can place it on bottom. what I suggest is use `"position: absolute;" ` and then try to fix the thing that breaks after this. `sometimes css issue is not really where you think it is`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use margin?

```
.form-text {
    margin-top: 20px; 
}
```

Comment: because height of the .form-error might be different